# I just want to know if exist any way to transform this code from Client Side Rending to SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side

```
'use client'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import DesktopProduct from './DesktopProduct'
import MobileProduct from './MobileProduct'
import { useGetProductQuery } from '@/redux/services/productsFetch'

const ProductContainer = ({ id }: { id: string }) => {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false)
  const [desktop, setDesktop] = useState(false)

  const { data } = useGetProductQuery(id)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 720) {
      setMobile(true)
    } else {
      setDesktop(true)
    }
    addEventListener('resize', () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 720) {
        setMobile(true)
        setDesktop(false)
      } else {
        setDesktop(true)
        setMobile(false)
      }
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {mobile && data && <MobileProduct data={data} />}
      {desktop && data && <DesktopProduct data={data} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The application consists of two totally different pages for both mobile phones and computers. The internal components do not work with any type of data that can be handled on the client. Therefore, in terms of performance, it would be much better to work with SSR. I have tried different ways one of which is to play with the CSS of the page and it worked but I would like to know if there is any way to fix it apart from playing with the CSS

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is contained within the logic defined in `setMobile()` and `setDesktop()` as it runs on the client side, can we see that? But yes, you should be able to load anything you need using ajax (but that isn't SSR as it is JS) and although it may even take a few seconds to process, it won't lock page render and you can add a spinner or something for visual interactivity prior to the data being added to the correct location on the page

Comment: You cannot transform a React component code from Client Side Rendering to SSR. All you can do is to ask the component to do some stuffs if it's on Server, and some other stuffs if it's on Client. To get it to render at Server Side, you need some special configuration to catch the request at Server side (NodeJS), and setup a virtual DOM to render it in HMTL while on Node, and then forward it to client. Pretty complex if doing from scratch, but there are some Pre-Setup that could help, like Frameworks NextJS, Gatsby, or Razzle. You can go manual setup for learning, but it might bother you.

Comment: CSR: Send very Basic HTML skeleton codes + Full React Application and Component codes so that browser can create the Full HTML codes.
SSR: Use Virtual DOM to render Components in Server with NodeJS and send Full HTML codes + Client Side React Application Component codes that will add or change the necessary HTML codes.

Comment: See this to get and idea of the minimal codes (NOT PRODUCTION READY as they mention in it): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering